# Real centroid plugin QGIS3

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, centroids

I am looking to use realcentroid where I'm assuming it puts all points within the polygons rather than the tool in QGIS Vector -> geom -> centroid tool, which in my result some bendier polygons have their centroids placed outside - the geometric centroid? The real centroid plugin doesnt install in QGIS v3 - do these get updated with releases?

Answer (score 8):

Third party plugins like this are dependant on their author to update for new versions. I'd suggest using the built in "point on surface" algorithm from the processing toolbox instead

Comment: It has been updated to QGIS 3.